# VBA LoadFromFile crashes on large files

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, adodb

I try to load chunks of a (really) large file in VBA:

```
Set dataStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

dataStream.Type = adTypeBinary
dataStream.Open
dataStream.LoadFromFile localDirectory & "\" & objFile.Name

byteBuffer = dataStream.Read(bufferSize)
```

If I understand correctly, the only amount of memory needed at a given time is bufferSize. Still, Access crashes at the LoadFromFile statement.

Is there a more robust way to read chunks from large files in VBA than ADODB.Stream?

I already tried [How to Transfer Large File from MS Word Add-In (VBA) to Web Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803294/how-to-transfer-large-file-from-ms-word-add-in-vba-to-web-server) (but that has problems with large files, too. Get fails unpredictably with Error 63).

Comment: How large is your file? How large is your buffer? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c

Comment: Afaik, synchronous ADO streams do store all data in memory (documentation on this is poor but I haven't found anything to the contrary). So you need both the full file in memory, as well as a copy of the buffer. But why do you want to use a stream at all? VBA's native read can read chunks.

Comment: @user10186832 The file is way above 2gb, sometines 10gb, sometimes 50. My buffer is 10mb. The code works fine with 500MB files and the like.

Comment: @ErikA the Get command from VBA fails when I hit the 2gb threshold while reading (the first 2gb read fine)

Comment: Ah, if you're going above that, you can always resort to WinAPI to read files, and will generally have a bad time using most COM/VBA stuff, as nearly all VBA uses 32-bits ints to track things.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's how I solved it

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(localDirectory)
Set sourceFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(localDirectory & "\" & objFile.Name)
strChunk = sourceFile.Read(bufferSize)
```

and then convert the string to a byte array:

```
Function StringToByteArray(str As String) As Byte()
Dim i As Long
Dim b() As Byte
ReDim b(Len(str) - 1) As Byte
For i = 1 To Len(str)
    b(i - 1) = Asc(Mid(str, i, 1))
Next i
StringToByteArray = b
End Function
```

The usual StrConv method does not work correctly! Therefore the method.

Comment: If as @ErikA says the `ADODB.Stream` method reads all the input file into memory then it might work on a computer with oceans of memory. (if you have one!)

Answer (score 0):

Command **dataStream.LoadFromFile** tries to load the entire file into RAM. You can check it yourself through the Task Manager.
Simple methods give more opportunities, so I suggest it be simpler. Below is the code that I applied to a 50GB file – and my computer didn't experience any problems, except that processing such a file will take a lot of time. But nothing freezes, and the process can be controlled as you like.

```
Dim fname As String
Dim fNo As Integer
Const bufferSize = 1024
Dim nextBytes(bufferSize) As Byte
Dim offset As Variant

fname = "C:\Path\BinaryFile.vdi"
fNo = FreeFile()
Open fname For Binary Access Read As #fNo
offset = 1
Do
    Get #fNo, offset, nextBytes
    offset = offset + bufferSize
    ' Do Something
    If EOF(fNo) Then Exit Do
Loop
Close #fNo
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - this is just as in the linked example.

On my system the Get command fails with error 63 just at the 2GB border.

With your code, if I understand correctly, you always read the same 1024 bytes beginning 1024 bytes from the beginning of the file (the 1024 parameter in the Get command is the offset from the beginning of the file). Please correct me if I am too dumb :-)

Thanks again!

Comment: yes, you right, fixed

Comment: But you also right about 2Gb, because of long limit )

Comment: It looks like this is really a problem, and you need to write a library in c# or another language to process files, the size of which is beyond long. Accordingly, the code I proposed works only for files, roughly speaking, up to 2 gigabytes in size.